# Nifi EvaluateXPath

Tags: java, apache-nifi

I have a problem with this XML in Nifi processor EvaluateXPath

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<s:Envelope xmlns:s="http://....">
    <s:Body>
        <GetDataSetResponse xmlns="http://....">
         <GetDataSetResult xmlns:a="http://...."xmlns:i="http://....">
            <a:ByteListFile>BLABLABLA</a:ByteListFile>
            <a:CodEsito>OK</a:CodEsito>
            <a:DescEsito>OK</a:DescEsito>
            <a:OutputValue>1</a:OutputValue>
         </GetDataSetResult>
      </GetDataSetResponse>
   </s:Body>
</s:Envelope>
```

i want to check this out  BLABLABLA , but nifi doesn't want to let me.. i use this expression

'''
/s:Envelope/s:Body/GetDataSetResponse/GetDataSetResult/a:ByteListFile
'''

the error is : Prefix s han not been declared

someone help me! THX

Comment: EvaluateXPath does not support namespaces. just remove all `s:` prefixes from xpath

Comment: I tried but nothing, it returns NO MATCH, as a solution I found this

''' //*[local-name()='ByteListFile']  '''

Answer (score 0):

You can try to replace your namespace prefix with asteriks:

```
/*:Envelope/*:Body/GetDataSetResponse/GetDataSetResult/*:ByteListFile
```

BUT GetDataSetResponse and GetDataSetResult have owns namespaces. This might not work. If is the case, you can add two additional EvaluateXPath in sequence and get each of then in sequence.